# Put a text on an uploaded image in overleaf

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I have one predefined image and I want to add a text on that. Could you please help me with it? Here is a simple of the my case. I want to add the text there A+B= C+D

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth]{test2.jpg}
  \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]